# I am trying to make an apk its generated but with this error Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'

Tags: windows, react-native

> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets
>   Scanning folders for symlinks in C:\react-native\first_app\node_modules (109ms)
>   Scanning folders for symlinks in C:\react-native\first_app\node_modules (47ms)
>   warning: the transform cache was reset.
>   Loading dependency graph, done.

Unable to resolve module `AccessibilityInfo` from `C:\react-native\first_app\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\react-native\react-native-implementation.js`: Module `AccessibilityInfo` does not exist in the Haste module map

This might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968
To resolve try the following:
  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
  3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.  4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.

  > Process 'command 'cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 42s
12 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 11 up-to-date

Comment: app is generated with this  gradlew assembleRelease -x bundleReleaseJsAndAssets someone help please i am using windows 10

Comment: can you please tell what version of React-Native you are using?

Comment: react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.56.0

Comment: I have tried this also   react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output App/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest App/src/main/res/
Command `bundle` unrecognized. Make sure that you have run `npm install` and that you are inside a react-native project.

Comment: someone please help

Comment: Looks like you are running command in wrong directory, I've added answer for your ease, kindly try that and let me know if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11696#issuecomment-270428347), It may be because of you did not bundled correctly for android.

You can add following script
`"bundle-android": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/"`

into `scripts` of your `package.json`

and the run `npm run bundle-android`

after that try running `gradlew assembleRelease -x bundleReleaseJsAndAssets` in `android` directory of your project. Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: BUNDLE  [android, dev] ./index.js ▓░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░ 6.3% (1/4), failed.         no error after this.

Comment: error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `AccessibilityInfo` from `C:\react-native\first_app\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\react-native\react-native-implementation.js`: Module `AccessibilityInfo` does not exist in the Haste module map                                                                                                         this error came before bundle started.

Comment: BUNDLE  [android, dev] ./index.js ▓░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░ 6.3% (1/4), failed. cmd stuck at this I don't know

Comment: can you please follow [this thread](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14209) for this `AccessibilityInfo` issue

Comment: also it will be great if you share your `package.json` with me.

Comment: {
  "name": "first_app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest",
    "bundle-android": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/"
  },

Comment: "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.4.1",
    "react-native": "0.56.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.4.2",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "5.0.2",
    "jest": "23.4.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.4.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}

Comment: I'll try reproducing your issue, and will let you know soon.

Comment: I am stuck in it from the morning please someone help

Comment: Looking for JS files in
   C:\react-native\first_app


Metro Bundler ready.

Loading dependency graph, done.

Comment: Have you tried degrading `react-native version` from `0.56.0` to `0.55.4`? meanwhile I'll try reproducing the issue, and find some exact solution than this workaround.

Comment: When I run the bundle command, it says this: `error ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\Dev\ReactNativeBuildError\AwesomeProject\android\app\src\main\assets\index.android.bundle'.`